JavaScript primitive variable has different values for different inline functions?
I am facing a very weird phenomenon regarding JavaScript variables, scopes and closures.
Here is a code for a React Native application:
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector, GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

let someVar = false;

const JsTest = () => {
    const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
        .onUpdate(() => {
            someVar = true;
            console.log('someVar is set to true');
        })
        .onEnd(() => {
            console.log(`someVar: ${someVar}`);
        });
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}></View>
            </GestureDetector>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

export default JsTest;

When I touch the screen, onUpdate callback is called so it sets the someVar to true.
When I release my finger, onEnd is fired but the value of someVar is false.
Here are the logs:
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar: false

However, if I create variables for callbacks instead of passing them inline, the value of someVar is successfully updated.
Here is the altered code:
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector, GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

let someVar = false;

const JsTest = () => {
    const onUpdate = () => {
        someVar = true;
        console.log('someVar is set to true');
    };
    const onEnd = () => {
        console.log(`someVar: ${someVar}`);
    };
    const gesture = Gesture.Pan().onUpdate(onUpdate).onEnd(onEnd);
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}></View>
            </GestureDetector>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

export default JsTest;

Console output:
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar is set to true
 LOG  someVar: true
 LOG  someVar: true
 LOG  someVar: true

How is this even possible? Note that someVar is not a state variable, not a ref, it's not even in the component function, it's a top level variable in the file itself. So all the other functions in the file should have closure over it and be able to get its updated value. What's so special about inline functions? Why do they behave differently?
I also tried with ref (using useRef) and a variable inside the component function, the result is the same. The result is the same with regular functions (instead of arrow functions) as well.
Why does this happen?

Can you reproduce this without React, just ordinary event listeners?

Don't think so. This should be somehow related to gesture handler and react I think.

What I find confusing is that you get multiple "set to true" messages before the first "LOG someVar: true/false" messages. Shouldn't they alternate if one is for touch and the other is for release? Is it some kind of drag operation?

It's fine, onUpdate is fired while I drag my finger, that's why there are multiple logs.
However the 3 someVar: true logs in second case are weird, I agree.

Is this the exact code you're testing with? "it's not even in the component function, it's a top level variable in the file itself" - from your description, it sounds very much like you accidentally redeclared it in the onUpdate function (maybe as a parameter?) and the refactoring to standalone functions just concealed the mistake.

@Bergi, yes, of course this is the exact code. When I encountered this issue I was using useRef hook and noticed the value is not updated. Then I tried to simplify the case to understand what's going on and came up with this.
You can create a fresh react native application and copy paste this code to reproduce.

What’s the compiled output in each case? (Reconfigure the build to output well-formatted code if necessary.)

This sounds like a bug in React. I don't know what kind of hooks it uses in the parser to allow embedding HTML, but maybe it's impacting this.
